# clearing fields after submitting form pops field required message

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I coded a simple form to enter user details and display inputted data in the same page in a table.

So in the JavaScript part I defined two functions called myCreateFunction() and myClearFunction().

I also added required attribute to all elements (ex- text/number fields, dropdown list)

While I am testing this form , after I entered and click submit it creates new row in the table and display detail also it clears all fields,

And there ***please fill this field*** popped .

I tried solutions on internet and nothing worked.

Can anybody help me figure it out why it pops out and how to fix it ?

> HTML :

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" id="btn_clear" onclick="myClearFunction()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_submit" onclick="myCreateFunction();myClearFunction();">
```

> Javascript :

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value = ""

    function myCreateFunction() {
      var Ifname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
      var Ilname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
      var Igender = document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value;
      var Iage = document.getElementById("num_age").value;
      var Ibyear = document.getElementById("num_birthyear").value;
      
      if (Ifname != "") {
        if (Ilname != "") {
          if (Igender != "") {
            if (Iage != "") {
              if (Ibyear != "") {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                
                cell1.innerHTML = Ifname;
                cell2.innerHTML = Ilname;
                cell3.innerHTML = Igender;
                cell4.innerHTML = Iage;
                cell5.innerHTML = Ibyear;
                
                //myClearFunction()
              }        
            } 
          }
        }
      }     
    }
    function myClearFunction() {
      document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value = "";
      document.getElementById("num_age").value = "";
      document.getElementById("num_birthyear").value = "";
    }

    </script>
```

Full Code : https://codeshare.io/YLbDlN

Comment: Since it's a submit button, the browser performs validation when you click on it, so it complains about the empty fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are clearing out the feilds the HTML5 validation is triggered and resulting in the error. To disable it completely we can prevent default behaviour of submit button with `event.preventDefault();`. Since you need it if the form is invalid we can change your code a little bit so that HTML5 validation is disabled only if all the fields are filled, you can do something as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<style>
    td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    h1 {
        padding-left: 80px;
    }
    td,th {
        font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    select {
        font-size: 17px;
        max-width: 88%;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #btn_submit {
        font-size: 20;
        width: 115px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }
    #btn_clear {
        font-size: 20;
        width: 100px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-left: -40px;
    }
    #myTable {
        color:darkblue;
        margin-top: -50px;
        float: center;
        margin-left: 500px;
        padding: 5px.5px,5px,5px;
    }
    #entry {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Entry Form </h1>

<form onsubmit="return false;" id="form">
<table id="entry">
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="first_name" required></br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="last_name"  required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="dropdown_gender" required>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
          <option value="Unspecified">Unspecified</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="num_age" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Birth Year</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="num_birthyear" required></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Clear" id="btn_clear" onclick="myClearFunction(event)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_submit" onclick="myCreateFunction(event)"></td>
</tr>   
</table>
</form>

</br></br>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="170px">&nbsp;First Name&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="170px">&nbsp;Last Name&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="120px">&nbsp;Gender&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="80px">&nbsp;Age&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="120px">&nbsp;Birth Year&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<script>
    document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value = ""

    function myCreateFunction(event) {
      var Ifname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
      var Ilname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
      var Igender = document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value;
      var Iage = document.getElementById("num_age").value;
      var Ibyear = document.getElementById("num_birthyear").value;
      
      if (Ifname != "") {
        if (Ilname != "") {
          if (Igender != "") {
            if (Iage != "") {
              if (Ibyear != "") {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                
                cell1.innerHTML = Ifname;
                cell2.innerHTML = Ilname;
                cell3.innerHTML = Igender;
                cell4.innerHTML = Iage;
                cell5.innerHTML = Ibyear;
                
                myClearFunction(event);
              }        
            } 
          }
        }
      }     
    }
    function myClearFunction(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("dropdown_gender").value = "";
      document.getElementById("num_age").value = "";
      document.getElementById("num_birthyear").value = "";
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```